# How to delay each iteration of a looping a-frame animation with aframe-animation-component

Tags: aframe

In the included example, there are two animations using practically identical settings, with the exception of `<a-animation>`'s `begin` property being swapped with `aframe-animation-component`'s `delay`.

`<a-animation>`'s `begin` property delays the animation in each iteration, which is the desired effect in this case. The `aframe-animation-component` doesn't seem to mirror this functionality with `delay`, at least with these settings.

Is this possible using `aframe-animation-component` without needing to use `AFRAME.anime` directly?

[CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/dansinni/pen/vdvZVb)

**Code:**

```
<!-- Using <a-animation> begin -->

<a-box color="red" position="-1 1 -4">
  <a-animation attribute="material.opacity"
             begin="4000"
             from="0.1"
             to="1"
             dur="1000"
             repeat="indefinitely">
  </a-animation>
</a-box>


<!-- Using aframe-animation-component delay -->

<a-box color="red" position="1 1 -4"
     animation="property: material.opacity;
                delay: 4000;
                from: 0.1;
                to: 1;
                dur: 1000;
                loop: true;">
</a-box>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I looked into `aframe-animation-component` code (the version you're using) and it seems that the delay is applied before *first* run of animation. You can either:

1. Copy the component's code and modify it so it works as you expect it to.
2. According to this piece of source code from `aframe-animation-component`:

   ```
   onStartEvent: function () {
       // Include the delay before each start event.
       if (this.data.delay) {
         setTimeout(this.beginAnimation, this.data.delay);
         return;
       }
       this.beginAnimation();
     },
   ```

   You can use a little workaround. Don't use `loop: true`, instead use `startEvents: your-custom-event`. The animation will start every time `your-custom-event` will be emitted by your entity. In addition, your entity will emit `animationcomplete` ([docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-animation-component)) when animation ends - so you can listen for `animationcomplete` event and call `el.emit("your-custom-event")` to trigger it again and again to mock `loop: true` functionality and achieve desired effect, without modifying original component.